# I able to get data from service layer But not visible in hTML page

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

**Component.ts**

```
export class NewExpenseComponent {
   users: any[];
  toastConfig: ToasterConfig; 
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: ExpensesService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private toasterService: ToasterService
  ) {
    this.service.get_bussiness().subscribe(users => this.users = users,
      error => console.log(error));
  }  
}
```

**Service.ts.**

```
get_bussiness(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/payment/')
      .map(response => response)
      .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.statusText));
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBusinessType">Business Type</label>
        <select #businesstype class="form-control" id="business_type" required [(ngModel)]="model.business_type" name="business_type" #Type="ngModel">
            <option disabled>Select</option>
            <option (click)="businesstype" *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">{{user.pay_method}}</option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="Type.errors && (Type.dirty || Type.touched)" class="errors">
            <div [hidden]="!Type.errors.required" style="color:red;">
                * Please select One
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

In console im able to see the data but im not able to get that data in Html page

**console.log**

```
 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0
    :
    {id: 1, pay_method: "fuel"}
    1
    :
    {id: 2, pay_method: "card"}
    2
    :
    {id: 3, pay_method: "cash"}
    length
    :
    3
    __proto__
    :
    Array(0)
```

Here i have mentioned my Html,component.ts and also my service layer dropdown alone not working. i dont know how to do that?

Comment: Is any error on your console?

Comment: it throws error like Type Error: connot read property 'choose_payee' undefined and Error Context. but it is was another input other than that there is no error.

Comment: `choose_payee` there isn't in your code.
What is `choose_payee`?

Comment: Choose_payee is an another input box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to send a comment, but I can't to do that yet.
Well, I read your code carefully and don't see obviously errors, expect one.

```
(click)="businesstype"
```

What it mean? It's just local template variable which must contains form object. Are you sure that console has no errors? We must to have more info about problem for resolving it.

Comment: Sorry i forget to remove that but if i remove also it was not working.

Comment: Anyway, tell me please log in your console. Probably you have some errors? ***ngFor** loop should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async** as we are getting data from observable.

```
 <select #businesstype class="form-control" id="business_type" required [(ngModel)]="model.business_type" name="business_type" #Type="ngModel">
            <option disabled>Select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let user of users|async" [value]="user.id">{{user.pay_method}}</option>
        </select>
```